# when i used SingleChildScrollView design changed

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:facebook/widgets/custome_text_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff3B5999),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: const Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.facebook,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 70,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            const CustomeTextField(labelText: 'Email or Phone', width: 310),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 17,
            ),
            const CustomeTextField(labelText: 'Password', width: 310),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                  const Color(0x004e68a1).withOpacity(.6),
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 220,
                child: const Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 200,
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text(
                  'Sign Up for facebook',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                )),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text(
                  'Forget Password ?',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Cant see any usecase of SingleChildScrollView.  it would easier for others if you include what did you expect and what went wrong while doing N way